# React Universal Webpack CSS-loader issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, server-side-rendering, css-loader

Does any one know what this Webpack error is caused by:

> *Module build failed: Unknown word (2:1)*
>
> *var content = require("!!../../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{\"importLoaders\":1}!./styles.css");*
>
> *if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];*

This occurs when running two instances of webpack, one for the client and one for the server. The client compile fine, however the server prodcuces this error. If I run the config scripts separately there are no issues. I'm assuming there is some kind of conflict with the same CSS file being processed twice? I would like to be able to implement isomorphic-style-loader however even with this loader in replace of style-loader the error occurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated, hit a wall with this one.

start.js

```
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const formatWebpackMessages = require('react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const paths = require('../config/paths');

// const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
//if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
const DEFAULT_CLIENT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 5678;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

// We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
// run on a different port. `detect()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_CLIENT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }

    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);

    // We do this before importing the wepack.config.client.dev otherwise
    // REACT_APP_CLIENT_PORT won't be set at new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified)
    process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_PORT = port
    const configWebpackClient = require('../config/webpack.config.client.dev');

    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    // we use different compiler
    //const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, configWebpackClient, appName, urls, useYarn);
    const compiler = webpack(configWebpackClient);

    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.

    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );

    const clientServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);

    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    clientServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan(`Starting the client on port ${port}...\n`));

      choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT)
        .then(portServer => {
          if (portServer == null) {
            // We have not found a port.
            return;
          }

          process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT = portServer;
          const configWebpackServer = require('../config/webpack.config.server');
          const compiler = webpack(configWebpackServer);
          const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, portServer);
          let isServerRunning;

          compiler.watch({ // watch options:
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
          }, function(err, stats) {

            const messages = formatWebpackMessages(stats.toJson({}, true));

            if (messages.errors.length) {
              console.log(messages.errors.join('\n\n'));
            }

            if (err)
              console.log('error on webpack server', err);

            if (!isServerRunning) {
              isServerRunning = true
              const nodemon = exec('nodemon --watch build/server build/server/bundle.js build/server/bundle.js')

              // This is to outpout in the terminal the child process
              nodemon.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log(data.toString());
              });
              nodemon.on('exit', function (code) {
                console.log('nodemon process exited with code ' + code.toString());
              });

              console.log(chalk.yellow(`Starting the server on port ${portServer}...\n`));
              // setTimeout(() => { openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser, {app: 'firefoxdeveloperedition'}) }, 1000);
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (err && err.message) {
            console.log(err.message);
          }
          process.exit(1);
        });
    });
    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        clientServer.close();
        process.exit();
      })
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

webpack.config.base.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
// const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
// const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');

const PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.

const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  bail: PROD,
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool:  PROD ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [],
  output: {},
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
    alias: {

      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      // ** ADDING/UPDATING LOADERS **
      // The "file" loader handles all assets unless explicitly excluded.
      // The `exclude` list *must* be updated with every change to loader extensions.
      // When adding a new loader, you must add its `test`
      // as a new entry in the `exclude` list for "file" loader.

      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.bmp$/,
          /\.gif$/,
          /\.jpe?g$/,
          /\.png$/,
        ],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
      // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {

          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
        },
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Remember to add the new extension(s) to the "file" loader exclusion list.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
};
```

webpack.config.client.dev.js

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

const base = require('./webpack.config.base');

const config = Object.assign({}, base)

config.entry = [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Errors should be considered fatal in development
    require.resolve('react-error-overlay'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
]

config.output = {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: '/',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'static/[id].[hash].hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'static/[hash].hot-update.json',
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
        path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath),
}

config.module.rules = config.module.rules.concat([
    // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
    // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
    // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
    // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
    // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        use: [
            {
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                options: {
                    importLoaders: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
])

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),

    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
        title: 'Webpack',
        excludeWarnings: true,
        alwaysNotify: true,
        contentImage: path.join(__dirname, '../ahamo-logo.png')
    }),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true
    }),
])

// Turn off performance hints during development because we don't do any
// splitting or minification in interest of speed. These warnings become
// cumbersome.
config.performance = {
    hints: false,
}

// Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
// Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
config.node = {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
},

module.exports = config
```

webpack.config.server.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const base = require('./webpack.config.base');
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

const config = Object.assign({}, base)

config.target = 'node'
config.entry = paths.serverIndexJs
config.externals = [nodeExternals()] // / in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
config.output = {
  path: paths.serverBuild,
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/'
}

config.module.rules = config.module.rules.concat([
  // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
  // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
  // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
  // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
  // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
      }, {
        loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
])

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
  // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
  // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
])

config.node = {
  console: false,
  global: false,
  process: false,
  Buffer: false,
  __filename: false,
  __dirname: false,
  setImmediate: false,
}

module.exports = config
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "universal-create-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server/bundle.js",
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "nodemon": "nodemon --watch build/server build/server/bundle.js build/server/bundle.js",
    "build-client": "node scripts/build-client.js",
    "build-server": "node scripts/build-server.js",
    "build": "npm run build-client && npm run build-server",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "author": "Campbell Stephenson: Ahamo Digital - Ahamo Pty Ltd",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN copyright.txt",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.0.17",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-http-proxy": "1.0.6",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-context-component": "^0.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-ssr-critical-styles": "^0.1.2",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-beta",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-loader": "1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.3",
    "node-style-loader": "0.0.1-alpha",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.5",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^3.0.0",
    "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to not be an issue with Webpack CSS-Loader or any other loader.

It was in fact how I was extending webpack.config.base.js by both webpack.config.client.dev.js and webpack.config.server.js

webpack.config.server.js resulted in it's config being combined with both base and client, hence the same css test being performed twice. This then causes the error:

```
Module build failed: Unknown word (2:1)

var content = require("!!../../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{\"importLoaders\":1}!./styles.css");

if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
```

The solution was to use wepack-merge to merge the base file rather than Object.assign({}, base) which to me is a much more elegant solution anyway.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been dealing with a similar problem for hours. I use webpack-merge already, but had the exact same problem you described. Re-organizing my configs to not include the same file multiple times solved the problem.